# Why am I seeing questions marks in the Debug window (stringstream issue)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to windows programming, and what experience I have to-date has been with C#.

I've been asked to work on a project written by a colleague in C++. He's avoided using any of the .Net functionality as he doesn't like it. I'm trying to add in some debugging output, here is my code:

```
    std::ostringstream strs;
    strs << "Average value: " <<  dbl_sum / (double)_buffer.size() << " Buffer Size: " << _buffer.size();
    std::string str = strs.str();
    OutputDebugString((LPCTSTR)str.c_str());
```

However, when I run the program I'm seeing lines like this in the Debug window:

```
?????????????????????????????›?
```

My best guess is that it's something to do with my conversion to `LPCTSTR`, but I got that method from an answer to an old question on here.

Comment: That cast only stopped the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong.  It didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Use OutputDebugStringA() to invoke the time machine.

Comment: Thanks, using OutputDebugStringA has fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hans Passant I managed to fix this problem. I changed my code to:

```
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << "Average value: " <<  dbl_sum / (double)_buffer.size() << " Buffer Size: " << _buffer.size() << std::endl;
std::string str = strs.str();
OutputDebugStringA((LPCSTR)str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess your project's char set is UNICODE

when you take ASCII string and convert it to UNICODE you got Gibberish.

To resolve this you need to use wide string types instead of string or to change your program charset to Multi-bytes
You'll need to change these types:
`string` to `wstring`,
`ostringstream` to `wostringstream`,
`"abc"`  to `L"abc"`

```
std::wostringstream strs;
strs << L"Average value: " <<  dbl_sum / (double)_buffer.size() << L" Buffer Size: " << _buffer.size();
    std::wstring str = strs.str();
    OutputDebugString(str.c_str());
```